# What is language use for level name in level 3 and 5 of Strider arcade game?

Tags: arcade, game

Arcade strider game show level name use different language follow Strider Hiryu (飛竜)'s adventure. But I not recognize languages for level  3 and level 5.

Can see titles in this video, [Arcade Longplay [052] Strider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZwzRRHn53k), at times:

- [6:24](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZwzRRHn53k&t=384) - Level 3

  [image: Strider - Level 3]
- [13:22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZwzRRHn53k&t=802) - Level 5

  [image: Strider - Level 5]

Other levels' titles:

1. Казахскся. ССР. A.D.2048
2. Сибйрь
3. ???
4. Amazon
5. ???

What language is used for levels 3 and 5?

Answer (score 15):

(Links are to the pertinent points in the video)

1. 00:15 [Казахскся. ССР. A.D.2048](https://youtu.be/FZwzRRHn53k?t=15)
   "Kazakh SSR A.D.2048"
   (Russian script, Latin date)
2. 02:49 [Сиби́рь](https://youtu.be/FZwzRRHn53k?t=169) <sup>1</sup>
   "Siberia"
   (Russian script)
3. 06:24 [געלראב](https://youtu.be/FZwzRRHn53k?t=384)
   "Balrog"<sup>2</sup> (written backwards and mis-spelled<sup>3</sup>)
   (looks like some kind of Aramaic or Hebrew script; Hebrew shown above)
4. 11:03 [Amazon](https://youtu.be/FZwzRRHn53k?t=663)
   "Amazon"
   (Latin/English script)
5. 13:23 [ᚦᛖ ᛏᚻᛚᚱᛒ ᛗᛟᛟᚾ](https://youtu.be/FZwzRRHn53k?t=803)
   Perhaps "The Third Moon"
   (Norse runes; literally "the thlrb moon"<sup>4</sup>)

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to @RadovanGarabík for pointing out the typo in my original transcription (I'm not very familiar with Slavic languages).

<sup>2</sup> Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strider_Hiryu

<sup>3</sup> Aramaic and its descendants (including Hebrew) are written right-to-left.  Thanks to @RossPresser for pointing out that it's also mis-spelled.

<sup>4</sup> To be pedantic, it's literally "ÞE THLRB MOON" with **Þ** being the letter *thorn* (pronounced *th*).  This letter existed in English up until Middle English<sup>5</sup>; currently only Icelandic still uses it.

<sup>5</sup> It is still used very rarely in English in phrases such as "Ye Olde Shoppe"<sup>6</sup> which should properly be pronounced "The Old Shop".

<sup>6</sup> **Y** is used for **Þ** since when the printing press was first invented (in Europe, at least) the presses were manufactured in Germany.  German didn't use the letter **þ** so when English publishers needed to print that letter they chose the most similarly-shaped letter that the presses did have, namely **y**.

( I love languages ☺ )

Comment: Typo... thir**b**, with a "b". Nice answer though :-)

Comment: @Greenonline To be pedantic, it's literally "ÞE THLRB MOON". Something makes me suspect the person who wrote it isn't a native speaker...

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Very interesting! You should add that little nugget to your answer, for clarity :-)

Comment: @Greenonline I changed **þ** to **th** for clarity since not a lot of people know that letter (IIRC only Icelandic still uses it).

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out just what you meant when you said that געלראב is written backwards. It's certainly written as געלראב in the game, and when געלראב is read forwards (right to left), it seems to say something similar to "gorlab" (according to Google Translate, at least). So, sure enough, if they were intending to write "balrog," they apparently wrote it backwards (perhaps mistakenly writing it from left to right).

Comment: also note that  Сибйрь should have been Сибирь (our perhaps the author meant to include the stress information, but that should be an acute accent)

Comment: The Hebrew actually has the L (lamed) and R (raysh) reversed.  Read in proper Hebrew order it says "GOLRAB", read left to right it says "BARLOG".